# Postgres: select the sum of values and then sum this again

Tags: postgresql, select, sum

I tried a lot but can´t find the right way.
If I select values in Postgres and sum them it looks like this:

```
SELECT name,sum(size) as total
FROM mytable group by name order by name;
```

How can I alter this so it also sum all values in total? I think I need a subselect but how?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(a.total)
FROM (SELECT sum(size) as total
      FROM mytable group by name) a
```

**UPDATE**
I'm sorry, I don't read that you want it all in the same query. For this reason the answer of **greg** it's better. However, other possibility if you have a postgresql version >= 9:

```
WITH mytableWith (name, sum) as
     (SELECT name, sum(size)
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY name)
SELECT 'grand total' AS name, 
       sum(sum) AS sum
FROM mytableWith
UNION ALL
SELECT name, sum
FROM mytableWith
```

Answer (score 10):

I would use the ROLLUP function on POSTRGESQL:

```
SELECT name,sum(size) as total
FROM mytable 
group by ROLLUP(name )
order by name;
```

This will give you a grand total of any value that you aggregate and can also be used for aggregating multiple columns.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you want all results with the same SELECT, you could do something like

```
SELECT 
  'grand total' AS name, 
   sum(size) AS sum 
FROM 
  mytable 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  name, 
  sum(size) AS sum 
FROM 
  mytable 
GROUP BY 
  name;
```

Hope it helps…

Answer (score 3):

Well this should help you:

```
select sum(innerselect.innertotal) as outertotal from 
    (select sum(size) as innertotal from mytable group by name) as innerselect
```