# PostgreSQL - making first row show as total of other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to make first row be different then the rest, so it would show total sum of the appropriate columns?

For example:

```
      fruits|a|b|c
       total|3|4|6
      apples|1|2|3
     bananas|1|1|2
     oranges|1|1|1
```

Is it possible to make query like that or it is against the logic of sql? 
It would be like this (ignoring the first row for now):

```
SELECT fruits, sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)
FROM basket
```

So the first row would be different. It would show word 'total' instead of fruit name, and would show total sum of a (1+1+1=3), b (2+1+1=4) and c (3+2+1=6). Is it possible to do like that? Thanks

Comment: You can simply `UNION ALL` the two queries (probably you have to cast your values as well).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres: select the sum of values and then sum this again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070855/postgres-select-the-sum-of-values-and-then-sum-this-again)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can avoid a second full scan of the table with a CTE:

**PostgreSQL 9.2 Schema**:

```sql
create table basket(fruits text, a integer, b integer, c integer);
insert into basket(fruits, a, b, c) values('apples', 1, 1, 1),
                                          ('apples', 0, 1, 2),
                                          ('bananas', 1, 1, 2),
                                          ('oranges', 1, 1, 1);
```

**Query**:

```sql
with w as ( select fruits, sum(a) a, sum(b) b, sum(c) c
            from basket
            group by fruits )
select * from w union all select 'total', sum(a), sum(b), sum(c) from w
```

**Results**:

```sql
|  FRUITS | A | B | C |
-----------------------
| bananas | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| oranges | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|  apples | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|   total | 3 | 4 | 6 |
```

*SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a682a/20)*

Comment: Thanks. I love postgres but this question makes me wish for [`rollup`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55331) which is a far more natural way of doing this.

Answer (score 13):

[This is now possible in version 9.5 of Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

**PostgreSQL 9.5 Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE basket(fruits text, a integer, b integer, c integer);
CREATE TABLE
INSERT INTO basket(fruits, a, b, c) values('apples', 1, 1, 1),
                                      ('apples', 0, 1, 2),
                                      ('bananas', 1, 1, 2),
                                      ('oranges', 1, 1, 1);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT coalesce(fruits,'total'), sum(a) a, sum(b) b, sum(c) c
FROM basket
GROUP BY ROLLUP((fruits))
```

**Results**

```
 fruits  | a | b | c
---------+---+---+---
 apples  | 1 | 2 | 3
 bananas | 1 | 1 | 2
 oranges | 1 | 1 | 1
 total   | 3 | 4 | 6
```

This `ROLLUP` is equivalent to using an expressions with `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT fruits, sum(a) a, sum(b) b, sum(c) c
FROM basket
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (fruits, ())
```

Each sublist in the `GROUPING SETS` is interpreted the same way as though it were directly in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 'total' AS fruits, sum(a), sum(b), sum(c) FROM basket
UNION ALL
SELECT fruits, sum(a), sum(b), sum(c) FROM basket GROUP BY fruits
```