# How to add a 'total' row in a grouped query (in Postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

How do I add a row to the end of this SELECT so I can see the total of the grouped rows? (I need the total for 'money' and 'requests':

```
SELECT 
    organizations.name || ' - ' || section.name as Section, 
    SUM(requests.money) as money, 
    COUNT(*) as requests
FROM 
    schema.organizations
   -- INNER JOINs omitted --
WHERE 
    -- omitted --
GROUP BY 
    -- omitted --
ORDER BY 
    -- omitted --
```

Running the above produces:

```
|*Section*  | *Money* | *Requests*|
|-----------|---------|-----------|
|BMO - HR   |564      |10         |
|BMO - ITB  |14707    |407        |
|BMO - test |15       |7          |
```

Now what I want is to add a total to the end of that which would display:

```
|BMO - Total|15286    |424        |
```

---

I have tried a few things, and ended up by trying to wrap the select in a WITH statement and failing:

```
WITH w as (
    --SELECT statement from above--
)
SELECT * FROM w UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'Total', money, requests from w
```

This produces weird results (I'm getting four total rows - when there should be just one.

Comment: You have to SUM() the results: SELECT 'Total', SUM(money), SUM(requests) from w

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a UNION query. In the query below, I add an artificial sortorder column and wrap the union query in an outer query so that the sum line appears at the bottom.

[I'm assuming you'll be adding your joins and group by clauses...]

```
SELECT section, money, requests FROM  -- outer select, to get the sorting right.

(    SELECT 
        organizations.name || ' - ' || section.name as Section, 
        SUM(requests.money) as money, 
        COUNT(*) as requests,
        0 AS sortorder -- added a sortorder column
     FROM 
        schema.organizations
    INNER JOINs omitted --
    WHERE 
        -- omitted --
    GROUP BY 
        -- omitted --
       --  ORDER BY is not used here


UNION

    SELECT
       'BMO - Total' as section,
        SUM(requests.money) as money, 
        COUNT(*) as requests,
        1 AS sortorder
    FROM 
        schema.organizations
        -- add inner joins and where clauses as before
) AS unionquery

ORDER BY sortorder -- could also add other columns to sort here
```

Answer (score 12):

The rollup function in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913166/1666637 answer might be a convenient way to do this. More on this and related functions here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS

Something like this, untested code

```
WITH w as (
    --SELECT statement from above--
)
SELECT * FROM w ROLLUP((money,requests))
```

Note the double parentheses, they are significant

Comment: Here is a working example 
`WITH w AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ( VALUES ('BMO - HR', 564, 10),
                  ('BMO - ITB', 14707, 407),
                  ('BMO - test', 15, 7)
         ) t (Section, Money, Requests)
)
SELECT Section, sum(Money), sum(Requests)
FROM w
GROUP BY ROLLUP ((Section, Money, Requests))`

Comment: A slight improvement on Francesco's excellent example above - added final order by with "nulls last" to force the rollup to the bottom:  WITH w AS (SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ('BMO - HR', 564, 10), ('BMO - ITB', 14707, 407), ('BMO - test', 15, 7) ) t (Section, Money, Requests) ) SELECT Section, sum(Money), sum(Requests) FROM w GROUP BY ROLLUP ((Section, Money, Requests)) order by section nulls last;